# how to display current expanded group at top of screen

Tags: scroll, expandablelistview

I have a expandable listview with textviews as rows and a webview as a child of each row (group). when user cliked on a group (row) webview with html loaded. after scrolling the webview towards end and then clicking another row doesnot show the group at top. it automatically scrolls down.

I want to scroll upwards so till  currently selected group is at top.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement `OnGroupClickListener` with return value `true` to prevent event flow. In the `OnGroupClick` you can use `setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);` to move just expanded group to the top of `ExpandableListView`. Also you need to call `expandGroup()` and `collapseGroup()` in the listener. But you should note what you will override general behavior of `ExpandableListView` in `ItemClick` event with expanding and collapsing groups, such as animate and etc.

Comment: I also have the same problem and if I use to return true from OnGroupClick method then I am not able to show the webview. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

```
listView.setSelectedChild(selectedGroupNo, selectedChildNo, true);
```

does the trick.